# NodeJS SSH2 module data returned in inconsistent format

Tags: node.js, ssh, putty

I am using the [ssh2 node module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2) to connect via ssh to a server. After which I run a command to list print ques and put them into an array, the command is lpstat -o.

When I use putty and ssh into a server and run this command, I get data returned like this:

```
LABEL008-2287           printeng          1024   Tue 08 Oct 2019 08:30:20 AM CDT
LABEL008-2288           printeng          1024   Tue 08 Oct 2019 08:30:20 AM CDT
LABEL002-2292           printeng          1024   Tue 08 Oct 2019 10:05:11 AM CDT
LABEL002-2293           printeng          1024   Tue 08 Oct 2019 10:05:11 AM CDT
```

However, when I use nodejs and run the command the data comes at times comes inconsistently (cut off) like this:

```
LABEL008-2287           printeng          1024   Tue Oct  8 08:30:20 2019
LABEL008-2288           printeng          1024   Tue Oct  8 08:30:20 2019
LABEL002-2294           printeng          1024   Tue Oct  8 10:05:12 2019
LABEL002-2298           printeng          1024   Tue Oct  8 10:05:12
2019
LABEL008-2299           printeng          1024   Tue Oct  8 10:05:15 2019
LABEL008-2300           printeng          1024   Tue Oct  8 10:05:17 2019
```

This is troublesome as I am needing to split the data by new line '\n\' and put it into an array which I am achieving like so:

```
}).on('data', function(data) {
          const myArray = data.toString().split('\n');
```

I am not sure if this is an issue or limitation with the node module itself or if I am missing an option or configuration with how the data stream should be handled.

Comment: The date formats in both output examples aren't the same, suggesting that the same command is not being run in both cases on the same system.

Secondly, you should never assume the contents of a chunk of data passed to `'data'` event handlers -- whether in `ssh2`, in another third party module, or even in node core. It could be one byte or a bunch of bytes. It could include a newline or maybe not. Just something to be aware of...

Comment: Yeah I changed/shortened the command for easier explanation here, but they both have the same output/command actually. Any recommendations on how to get around the data event handler issue? I need the data in an array to pass to a front end UI.

Comment: Wait until the command is finished before splitting the output?

Comment: I have tried that...i guess because it comes in chunks in the stream its just how it is intended to work unfortunately: https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2/issues/210